# Using Like Clause in Azure Mobile Services JavaScript Client

Tags: javascript, sql, azure-mobile-services

I am writing a JavaScript client for an Azure Mobile Service. I am trying to use the LIKE clause (or equivalent) in the JavaScript Where clause, when I am querying a table.
Does any one know how to do this?
[Essentially I want to see whether a string starts with a particular value or not]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `indexOf` function, which is supported in the function:

```
var table = client.getTable('tableName');
var queryValue = document.getElementById('txtField').value;
table.where(function(startsWith) {
    return this.name.indexOf(startsWith) === 0; // for 'contains', use >= 0
}, queryValue).read().done(function(results) {
    alert('Results: ' + JSON.stringify(results));
}, function(err) {
    alert('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

Comment: could also potentially use substring for starts with as well

Comment: In case of contains, you have to use >= since match can be on first index too.