# Azure mobile service - get row(s) based on matching string/substring value

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to read results from JavaScript azure mobile service and I want to return items with a specific values. I am using getTable(‘’).where.(‘’).read(‘’) to check if one of the returned json value match a specific pattern as shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22484501/using-like-clause-in-azure-mobile-services-javascript-client):

Here is my client side script:

```
function getSP() {

var spUser = client.getTable("User").where(function (contains) {

    return this.extraname.indexOf(contains) > 0;

}, "Eyad").read().done(function (results) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(results));
}, function (err) {
    alert("Error: " + err);
});}
```

And the request URL generated from client:

```
https://XYZ.azure-mobile.net/tables/User?$filter=(indexof(extraname,'Eyad') gt 0)
```

But the code above return an empty [] object form the service, while performing the same operation without the where() check clearly returns my intended value:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? How can I return the row(s) where the returned "extraname" contains the substring "Eyad"?

---

NOTE: I also have a custom read script on the service side, and you can see the "extraname" value is hardcoded for testing purposes:

```
function read(query, user, request) {
request.execute({
    success: function(results) {
        var now = new Date();
        results.forEach(function(item) {
            console.log(item.userjsondata);
            item.extraname = "Eyad";
        });
        request.respond(); //Writes the response
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Is the `extraname` variable also stored in the database, or is it only added dynamically in the server-side script? A `$filter` clause in the request URI (generated by a `where` call in the JS client) will be converted into a `WHERE` clause of the SQL statement to be sent to the database. If the column doesn't exist in the database, then it won't return anything (as you're seeing)

Comment: @carlosfigueira extraname is indeed added dynamically and it is not a column in the queried table. The reason I am doing this because the value of extraname will be calculated dynamically based on multiple column values. Is there a way to check against the dynamically added value?

Comment: Not directly - see my answer for more information.

Comment: I am having this exact problem what is a working solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're generating a new column dynamically, then there's no way to - directly - use a `$filter` clause to filter the results based on that value. Notice that you can write arbitrary code to calculate that value, so the mobile service runtime has no way to know what value it will end up generating, and cannot perform a filter based on that.

There are a couple of workarounds for your solution: if possible, you can send a `where` clause with the same expression that you use to generate the value. In some cases the service will accept that expressions in the `$filter` clause as well. That has the drawback that you'll end up with the same logic in two different places, and there's a big chance that you'll change one and end up forgetting to change the other.

Another alternative is to pass the parameter for which you want to query the generated property not in the `$filter` parameter (i.e., don't use the `where` function, but pass the parameters inside the `read` call. Those parameters will be passed to the `read` script in the `request.parameters` object, and you can add your logic to filter based on that value *after you're done reading from the database* (see below).

**Client:**

```
var spUser = client.getTable("User").read({mustContain: "Eyad").done(function (results) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(results));
}, function (err) {
    alert("Error: " + err);
});}
```

**Service:**

```
function read(query, user, request) {
    var mustContain = request.parameters.mustContain;
    request.execute({
        success: function(results) {
            var now = new Date();
            var filteredResults = [];
            results.forEach(function(item) {
                console.log(item.userjsondata);
                item.extraname = "Eyad";
                if (item.extraname.indexOf(mustContain) >= 0) {
                    filteredResults.push(item);
                }
            });
            request.respond(200, filteredResults); //Writes the response
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your comparison from this:

```
return this.extraname.indexOf(contains) > 0;
```

to this:

```
return this.extraname.indexOf(contains) >= 0;
```

A matched string can be (in your case, always) found in the first index. Therefore you have to use greater than OR equal to operator to handle that case.